# Why does widget.pack_forget() retain some widgets in Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm using this code to hide all the widgets in my Tkinter program:

```
def clearScreen():
    for widget in root.winfo_children():
        widget.pack_forget()
```

However, whenever I call this function, for a split second I can still see some of the widgets. When I change the function to this,

```
def clearScreen():
    for widget in root.winfo_children():
        widget.pack_forget()
    sleep(5)
```

This is how it appears [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJA0T.png) and [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMeMS.png) I call the function:

I tried to use `widget.update()` and `widget.update_idletasks()` because I thought that maybe the screen wasn't updating after I cleared all the widgets and that's why some were still showing, but this didn't work.

More relevant code here:

```
def optionsWindow():
    clearScreen()
    audio = ttk.Checkbutton(root, text="Audio Only", variable=audioToggle, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
    audio.pack(pady=20)
    backButton = ttk.Button(root, text="Back to Main", command=lambda: [clearScreen(), mainWindow()])
    backButton.pack(pady=20)

def clearScreen():
    for widget in root.winfo_children():
        widget.pack_forget()
    root.update()

inputBox = tk.Text(root, height=10, width=50, borderwidth=2, relief='groove')
downloadButton = ttk.Button(root, text="Download", command=downloadVideo)
optionsButton = ttk.Button(root, text="Options", command=optionsWindow)
progressBar = ttk.Progressbar(root, length=300)
statusText = ttk.Label(root)

def mainWindow():
    clearScreen()
    inputBox.pack(anchor='center', pady=20)
    downloadButton.pack(anchor='center', pady=10)
    optionsButton.pack(anchor='center', pady=10)
    statusText.pack(anchor='center', pady=20)
    statusText.config(text="")
```

Comment: Are some of those widgets using `place()` or `grid()` instead of `pack()` by any chance?

Comment: No, they all use `pack()`

Comment: Have you tried calling `root.update_idletasks()` after your `for` loop? (in place of `sleep`)

Comment: Just tried it, still getting the issue

Comment: Hmm...I'd have to see how the widgets are being instantiated

Comment: Just added the code where the widgets are being used

Comment: please provide a complete [mcve], and explain what we're supposed to do to see the problem.

Comment: Have you tried removing the call to `root.update()` in `clearWindow`? Calling `update` is going to cause the screen to refresh between clearing the window and creating the new window. If you remove the call, you won't see the changes until all of the changes  have been made.